# Почему можно передать ссылку на объект пользовательского типа данных, но нельзя передать сам объект?

Tags: c++

```
void func(class SD) {

}

class SD {

};
```

Почему код выше не работает, я ведь указываю компилятору что тип SD - это пользовательский тип данных тем самым объявил его.

```
void func(class SD&) {

}

class SD {

};
```

Почему это работает тогда?

Comment: Для передачи объекта по значению в определении функции `class SD` должен быть определен. А при передаче по ссылке, которая потом не используется, - нет

Comment: Почему это именно так? Я же могу и по значению никак не вызывать эту функцию

Comment: Чтобы скомпилировать первую функцию нужно знать размер объекта и вызвать его конструктор копирования.
Чтобы скомпилировать вторую функцию нужно знать размер ссылки (размеры всех ссылок одинаковы) и скопировать ссылку - переслать несколько байтов.

Comment: В ссылку можно завернуть указатель, просто хранящий адрес. А для передачи по значению нужен конструктор копий, которого пока нет. Если бы Вы определили класс, не написав явно конструктор копий, то он был бы создан автоматически. Но пока нельзя сделать даже этого, так как нет ни полей, ни размера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первом примере `class SD` - это так называемый неполный тип. Конструкция даёт компилятору знать, что это пользовательский тип, который определён полностью где-то в другом месте. И всё. На данном этапе компилятор не знает ни его размер, ни перечень конструкторов, членов класса. И поэтому не может сгенерировать никакой код с его участием.

С указателями и ссылками на неполные типы можно выполнить некоторые операции, но их, в основном, используют для того, чтобы передать их в другую единицу трансляции, в которой этот тип является полным. Ссылки и указатели всегда являются полными типами, так как их размер известен всегда.

## Критерии неполного типа

Рассмотрим, какие типы можно назвать неполными.

1. Тип `void`. При этом его невозможно сделать полным:

```
void a;   //Ошибка: это неполный тип.
void *b;  //Указатель - это полный тип. Но под этим указателем 
//может скрываться любой тип; при его разыменовывании нужно будет 
//предварительно преобразовать его в указатель на полный тип.
```

2. Класс, который был объявлен, но не определён (например, с помощью предварительного объявления):

```
class A;   //Это неполный тип.
class B{}; //Это полный тип.
class A{}; //Здесь класс A дополнен. С этого момента он стал полным типом.
```

3. Массив неизвестной длины:

```
extern int a[];     //это неполный тип.
extern int b[10];   //это полный тип.
```

4. Массивы, элементы которых имеют неполный тип:

```
class A;
A a[10];   //это неполный тип.
```

5. Перечисления, когда они были объявлены, но нижележащий тип ещё не определён.

## Что нельзя делать с неполными типами?

1. Определять и вызывать функции, которые принимают неполный тип как аргумент или возвращают его:

```
class A;
void f(A a){}  //ошибка: аргумент функции имеет неполный тип.
A f()        //Ошибка: функция возвращает неполный тип.
{
//Здесь и написать ничего не получится, так как объект неполного типа невозможно создать.
}
```

Особым случаем здесь будут функции, возвращающие `void`. Это неполный тип, но возврат функцией типа `void` трактуется как отсутствие возвращаемого значения.

2. Определять объект неполного типа (например, в теле функции):

```
class A;
A a1;        //Ошибка: попытка создания объекта неполного типа.
void f() {
    A a2;    //Ошибка: попытка создания объекта неполного типа.
    static A a3; //Ошибка: попытка создания объекта неполного типа.
}
```

3. Определять нестатический член класса неполного типа:

```
class A;
class B {
    A a;   //Ошибка: в классе B определён член неполного типа.
};
```

4. Выделять память для объекта неполного типа с помощью оператора `new`:

```
class A;
A *a = new A;  //Ошибка: попытка выделения памяти для неполного типа.
```

5. lvalue-to-rvalue conversion applied to a glvalue of type T;
6. Выполнять явное или неявное приведение типа к неполному типу;
7. a standard conversion, dynamic_cast, or static_cast to type T* or T&, except when converting from the null pointer constant or from a pointer to possibly cv-qualified void;
8. Выполнять доступ к членам класса неполного типа<sup>1</sup>:

```
class A;
A::static_member = 0;  //Ошибка: попытка доступа к статическому члену неполного типа

A* f();
A *a = f();
a->member = 0;   //Ошибка: попытка доступа к нестатическому члену неполного типа
```

9. Применять операторы `sizeof`, `typeid`, `alignof` к неполному типу:

```
class A;
size_t s = sizeof(A);  //Ошибка: попытка вычислить размер неполного типа.
```

10. Наследовать классы от неполного типа:

```
class A;
class B : public A {}; //Ошибка: попытка унаследовать неполный тип.
```

11. Выполнять присваивание неполного типа к lvalue:

```
class A;
A getA();    //Предположим, что эта функция имеет определение в другой единице трансляции, где тип A является полным
A a = getA();  //Но в этой единице трансляции тип A является неполным, поэтому присваивание запрещено.
```

12. Использовать неполный тип, а также ссылку и указатель на него в конструкции try-catch:

```
class A;
void f();
try
{
    f();
}
catch (A*)  //Ошибка: попытка использования указателя на неполный тип в try-catch.
{    
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> На [странице документации](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type) не указан отдельно запрет разыменовывания указателя на неполный тип, я объединил его c запретом на доступ к членам класса с помощью оператора `->`.

Comment: Было бы неплохо помочь с переводом п. 5, 7. Примеры ещё потом добавлю.

Comment: Ок, спасибо! Комментарий с вопросом удаляю, чтобы не мешался в будущем )

Comment: `void f(A a);  //ошибка: аргумент функции имеет неполный тип.` - неправильно. Как раз это можно, как предварительное определение.

Comment: функции `typeof` не бывает, есть `typeid`

Comment: @AlexGlebe, согласен, объявлять можно, определять нельзя. Исправил. И `typeid` тоже исправил.